# How to set SharePoint list column font color using JavaScript

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, javascript

My question can be answered via two different ways:

1) How can I set the font on columns = white (to fake them being hidden)? I currently tried to use `FieldName.fontcolor("white")` and `FieldName.fontcolor = '#ffffff'`; however neither of these worked.

2) Alternatively, am I able to access fields that are hidden (i.e. not visible on the SharePoint list)? I currently access fields using `ctx.CurrentItem["nj0z"]`, for example. However, if they are hidden, they cannot be accessed.

Ultimately, I would like to use column A for a calculation on column B; however, I do not want column A to be visible to the user!

I hope this is clear!

Answer (score 0):

You could try to hide the whole TR by [CSR](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views), sample code for your reference.

```
<script>
(function () {
   var overrideCtx = {};
   overrideCtx.OnPostRender = function(ctx) {
     var rows = ctx.ListData.Row;
     for (var i=0;i<rows.length;i++){
    //condition
       //var isApproved = rows[i]["_ModerationStatus"] == "Approved";
       //if (isApproved){
         var rowElementId = GenerateIIDForListItem(ctx, rows[i]);
         var tr = document.getElementById(rowElementId);
         tr.style.display = "none";
       //}
     }
   }
   SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(overrideCtx);
 })();
</script>
```

Comment: Interesting, I shall give this try and get back to you!